# Downloading files with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm currently trying to download an exe file using Powershell. This is the code that I've got:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www106.zippyshare.com/d/2pyiUtIr/39887/SimpleHelp%20Technician-window
s64-online%20%281%29.exe' -OutFile 'c:\simple\simegwg.exe'
```

The problem that I'm having is that when it downloads the file, it appears corrupted, so I cannot run it.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have pre-read a lot of posts. However, I cannot seem to correct this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the URL. I believe Zippyshare hosts files using dynamic URLs. The URL I got from your webpage is [https://www106.zippyshare.com/d/2pyiUtIr/49569/SimpleHelp%20Technician-windows64-online%20%281%29.exe](https://www106.zippyshare.com/d/2pyiUtIr/49569/SimpleHelp%20Technician-windows64-online%20%281%29.exe). And it works in Powershell as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you issue here is that the website changes the URL, the out-file of that URL is actually html.

If you change the outfile to output to .html you will see when you open the file contains html headers when opening the file in notepad etc.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www106.zippyshare.com/d/2pyiUtIr/39887/SimpleHelp%20Technician-windows64-online%20%281%29.exe' -OutFile 'c:\simple\simegwg.html'
```

However this will take you the file you are looking for...

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www106.zippyshare.com/d/2pyiUtIr/11504/SimpleHelp%20Technician-windows64-online%20%281%29.exe' -OutFile 'c:\simple\simegwg.exe'
```

As you can see in the URL "/39887/" has changed to "/11504/", and when doing the invoke-webrequest and outputting to .exe the file seems to be an executable. The new URL was taken by visiting the page using the url in your webrequest and copying the new link from the download button.

I would advise using a different file sharing service in future that supports persistent links, also zippyshare seems to try and redirect numerous sites which get flagged by eset and I assume other anti-virus/realtime protection services will do the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('link/name.exe','name.exe');
(New-Object -com Shell.Application).ShellExecute('name.exe');
```

Comment: Adding a little more detail explaining what this does, what the parameters mean, etc. would be helpful.